# How to Enforce HTTPS For ASMX Service

Tags: iis-7, https, asmx

I have a number of existing ASMX web services running on IIS7, and want to change them so that all requests and responses must be made over HTTPS.

The site is also running other pages like PHP and Classic ASP, so I can't just change the site root to serve HTTPS pages.

How can I set this per ASMX serivce (application), so that if somebody visits http://www.mydomain.com/MyService/ServiceName.asmx it either redirects them to https://www.mydomain.com/MyService/ServiceName.asmx or  returns a 404 error ?

Thoughts and best approach ?

Comment: Do I need to provide any further information to get a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with URL rewrite?

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)/ServiceName.asmx" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: If I set this rule and use "http://www.example.com/MyService/ServiceName.asmx" (http not https) I get an "Object moved" error and can not access the webservice. There is something more I have to do? (Using NET Framework 4.0)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be just to include the following code in the constructor of each service - allowing you to decide it on each service individually.

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    var sslUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace("http://", "https://");

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(string.Format("This service requires a SSL connection please go to {0}", sslUrl));
    Response.End();

    // Or simply redirect
    // Response.Redirect(sslUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect that @oexenhave used did not work for me. Instead I used the following (with a tip of the hat to @oexenhave for doing most of the good work)

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
  var sslUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace("http://", "https://");
  Context.RewritePath(sslUrl);
}
```

Add this into the asmx constructor.

Answer (score -3):

I will encourage you to use WCF instead of ASMX  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx.

For your above question, does this solve your issue?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302409.aspx

Thanks...