# converting a simple web service into a secured one in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, https, app-config

How can i convert a simple http://localhost... web service into https://localhost... service? Could any one provide a good example/tutorial in ASP.NET?

Comment: I have been successful  to create a simple http web service but failed when i tried https one. I have tried many thing in app.config. no Luck.

Comment: You don't need any special thing for working on https. That's not something that a web application needs to handle. You need to add the protocol in the IIS with the proper SSL certificate.

Comment: You can refer this stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242207/how-to-enforce-https-for-asmx-service